# Collision detection : myName nil value

Tags: lua, sdk, null, coronasdk

I'm trying to set up collision for my game with code from Corona SDK sample called "Collision Detection".
I'm getting this realy strange error every time ball collides with something -

> Runtime error
>           ...er 1\documents\corona projects\earthyball\level1.lua:114: attempt to concatenate field 'myName' (a nil value) stack traceback:
>           [C]: ?
>           ...er 1\documents\corona projects\earthyball\level1.lua:114: in function  <...er 1\documents\corona prRuntime error
>           ...er 1\documents\corona projects\earthyball\level1.lua:118: attempt to concatenate field 'myName' (a nil value) stack traceback:
>           [C]: ?

This is my code

```
    display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)

local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

physics.setScale( 60 )
physics.setGravity( 0, 12 )

system.setAccelerometerInterval( 100 )





function scene:createScene(event)
   local screenGroup = self.view




   bkg = display.newImage("bkg.png")
    screenGroup:insert(bkg)

    finish = display.newImage("finishflag.png")
    finish.x = 400
    finish.y = 260
    finish.myName ="flag"
    physics.addBody(finish,"static",element)

   blockl1 = display.newImage("blockl1.png")
   blockl1:setReferencePoint(display.CentreReferencePoint)
   blockl1.x = 165
   blockl1.y = 230
   physics.addBody(blockl1,"static",element)
   screenGroup:insert(blockl1)


   l1block2 = display.newImage("l1block2.png")
   l1block2:setReferencePoint(display.CentreReferencePoint)
   l1block2.x = 300
   l1block2.y = 90
   physics.addBody(l1block2,"static",element)
   screenGroup:insert(l1block2)

   line1 = display.newImage("line1.png")
   line1:setReferencePoint(display.CentreReferencePoint)
   line1.x = 230
   line1.y = 300
   physics.addBody(line1, "static", element)
   line1.myName = "pod"
   screenGroup:insert(line1)

   line2 = display.newImage("line1.png")
   line2:setReferencePoint(display.CentreReferencePoint)
   line2.x = 230
   line2.y = 10
   physics.addBody(line2, "static", element)
   line2.myName = "pod2"
   screenGroup:insert(line2)

   line1Ver = display.newImage("lineVer.png")
   line1Ver:setReferencePoint(display.CentreReferencePoint)
   line1Ver.x = 20
   line1Ver.y = 230
   physics.addBody(line1Ver, "static", element)
   screenGroup:insert(line1Ver)

   line2Ver = display.newImage("lineVer.png")
   line2Ver:setReferencePoint(display.CentreReferencePoint)
   line2Ver.x = 440
   line2Ver.y = 230
   physics.addBody(line2Ver, "static", element)
   screenGroup:insert(line2Ver)



   ball = display.newImage("ball.png")
   ball.x = 50
   ball.y = 30
   physics.addBody(ball,"dynamic",{density=3.1, bounce=0.6, friction=0.5, radius=17})
   finish.myName ="ball"
   screenGroup:insert(ball)


end



function scene:enterScene(event)


finish.collision = onLocalCollision
finish:addEventListener( "collision", finish )

line1.collision = onLocalCollision
line1:addEventListener( "collision", line1 )

line2.collision = onLocalCollision
line2:addEventListener( "collision", line2 )

ball.collision = onLocalCollision
ball:addEventListener( "collision", ball )


end


function onLocalCollision( self, event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then

        print( self.myName .. ": collision began with " .. event.other.myName )

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then

        print( self.myName .. ": collision ended with " .. event.other.myName )

    end
end

function onTilt( event )
    physics.setGravity( ( 12.5 * event.xGravity ), ( -12.5 * event.yGravity ) )
end



function scene:exitScene(event)

end

function scene:destroyScene(event)

end


Runtime:addEventListener( "accelerometer", onTilt )

element = { friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 }



scene:addEventListener("createScene",scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene",scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene",scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene",scene)

return scene
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Your all objects are a part of physics. That means, they all collide with each other. Thats why in every collision, it is possible to call a collision event listener. What I'm trying to saying is that, you have a collision event listener on your ball object, line1, line2 and finish. And you think that if there is a collision pnly between these objects your event listener will be called. But for example, when ball object collides with line2ver, line1ver etc., your event listener ball() is calling and that function trys to reach line1ver.myName which does not exist.

So, you must wheter add .myName part to all your objects, or just didn't print .myName part.

And a little tip to you:
I think you want to detect collisions with ball - other objects. For that purpose, you can use just one collision event listener, which is ball()

Hope it helps...